# Mysql Database Column naming that will cause less problems with Sequelize ORM tool

Tags: mysql, orm, naming-conventions, naming

What is the best practice for naming columns in MySql Database when the test team will be using an ORM tool together with cypress to inject and remove data? - test data will be in JSON while the current DB is in MySQL.

For example, let's say I have a software company that has logins for an admin system (Tech Support staff users), dealers, but I also have customers (Users).

In My Table I have the following columns:

1-dealer

first_name | last_name | address

2-staffuser

first_name | Last Name | address

3-customeruser

first_name | last_name | address

**Is this the "sane way"? or should it be:**

1-dealer

dealer_first_name | dealer_last_name | dealer_address

2-staffuser

staff_user_first_name | staff_user_last_name | staff_user_address

3-customeruser

customer_user_first_name | customer_last_name | customer_user_address

Comment: I am not a fan of prefixing column names with the name of the table. Doing that appears to be an attempt to solve a problem. Personally, I think there are better approaches to solving whatever those problems are. For example, let's follow best practice pattern and qualify *all* column references with a table name or alias, and "ambiguous column" errors won't ever be a problem, no matter our column naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Your models will have specific names in your return JSON so there would be no confusion on the front end with duplicate property/column naming in diff objects... but also you can alias your columns in sequelize if you needed to... i kind of wonder why you don't just have a user table with a user type column that was equal to either staff/dealer/customer tho if the values are the same